# Laravel: Passing request to core function?

Tags: php, laravel

In order to report my error I need access to a `Request`, but I can't get one in my report function in `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php`?

Reporting:

```
public function report(Exception $exception) {
    if (strlen($exception->getMessage()) > 0 && $this->shouldReport($exception)) {
        $agent = new Agent();
        $errorLog = new ErrorLog;
        $errorLog->error_message = $exception->getMessage();
        $errorLog->error_file = $exception->getFile();
        $errorLog->error_line = $exception->getLine();
        $errorLog->request_ip = $request->ip();
        $errorLog->request_url = $request->root();
        $errorLog->request_device = $agent->isDesktop() ? 'Desktop' : ($agent->isMobile() ? 'Mobile' : 'Tablet');
        $errorLog->request_system = $agent->platform() . ' ' . $agent->version($agent->platform());
        $errorLog->request_browser = $agent->browser();
        $errorLog->error_happened_to = (Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->username : 'Guest');
        $errorLog->save();
    }

    parent::report($exception);
}
```

Failing to pass one results in the following error:

> Undefined variable: request

Comment: it's because you don't have one. try Hanlin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can access request in any where using helper function `request()` directly, in your case just use `request()->ip()`